# How to create PDF reports with PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, export

I am developing an project with my University mates and we are stucked in the goal "Generating PDF Reports".

Basically, i want to create it using my PHP + MySQL backend to generate the PDF file that my users will be able to download (or maybe i send via email attachment)

Hope you guys help me.

Comment: by typing your title in gaagle, i get this **[duplicate SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132015/best-way-to-create-a-pdf-with-php)** . Learning to google is an essential skill to generate pdf's.

Comment: Use TCPDF library. https://tcpdf.org/